# Excel 2013 VBA Add multiple values in ActiveFilter

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form which has checkboxes to select values from "**Tax**", "**Account**", "**Invoice**".
I want to filter the data based on what user selects (user can select one or more options).

I'm using this line, but it does not fetch any results:

```
Dim CritArray(0 To 3) As String
        CritArray(0) = "Tax"
        CritArray(1) = "Accounting"
        ActiveSheet.Range("$B$4:$H$12").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=CritArray
```

There is no error, but the resulting sheet shows no data.
Can any one help?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to select any rows in column D (i.e. `Field:=3`) which have values of "Tax" or "Accounting", you will need to include `Operator:=xlFilterValues`, i.e.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$B$4:$H$12").AutoFilter Field:=3, _
                                           Criteria1:=CritArray, _
                                           Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Without that parameter, it is just picking out rows that have the same value as the last element of your array (i.e. `CritArray(3)`), which is empty in your example.